# OData Nested array parameters

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to post a 2 collections as parameters but it fails and parameters are null. I would like to post multiple questions each containing multiple answers. I am using Web Api 2 and OData v4.

```
        var questionsArray = builder.Action("QuestionsArray");
        questionsArray.CollectionParameter<Questions>("questions");
        questionsArray.CollectionParameter<MultipleChoiceAnswers>("options");
        questionsArray.EntityParameter<Quizs>("quizs");
```

The quizs is just to link the questions to a quiz

Comment: Please show your implementation of the action and the corresponding invocation from the client.

Comment: Found the problem. The MultipleChoiceAnswers was an object inside the questions not its own object. Thanks anyway :)